# Dart Streams blocking

Tags: stream, dart

I am using the BLoC pattern for a Futter app but I can't get both listeners to work.
If I call the `loggedIn.listen()` before the `register.listen()` the `register.listen()` won't work anymore and vice versa.

```
AuthBloc({this.authService}) {
    Stream<CrendentialsDetail> detailStream = Observable.combineLatest2(
      emailStream,
      passwordStream,
      (email, password) {
        return CrendentialsDetail(email: email, password: password);
      },
    );

    Stream<AuthResponse> loggedIn ... code ...

    Stream<RegisterResponse> register ... code ...

    register.listen((RegisterResponse res) {
      Scaffold.of(_context).showSnackBar(
        new SnackBar(
          content: new Text(res.message),
        ),
      );
    }, onError: (error) {
      Scaffold.of(_context).showSnackBar(
        new SnackBar(
          content: new Text(error.message),
        ),
      );
    });

    loggedIn.listen((AuthResponse user) {
      currentUserSubject.add(user);
      _goToHome();
    }, onError: (error) {
      Scaffold.of(_context).showSnackBar(
        new SnackBar(
          content: new Text(error.message),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: As written nothing should prevent both listeners from getting called. Maybe the side effects of both listeners is hiding the effects of the others? Have you tried logging to see if both of them are getting hit? Otherwise the bug likely lies in other details of the code. Can you provide a minimal repro?

Comment: I tried and changed the code so that the `.listen()` was called directly on the `Stream`s with `detailStream` object instantiated as parameter. And it work. Don't know why.

Comment: It's not clear what "won't work" means.

Are you trying to listen twice on a single-subscription Stream? If so the second listen should throw. I'm not sure if something in RxDart would be swallowing that exception or something like that. All in all this depends on a lot of details you haven't shown here. If you could narrow down to a minimal repro we might be able to diagnose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I'm using right now. Could someone explain to me why is works and my question not?

```
AuthBloc({this.authService}) {
    Observable(loginSubject.stream).withLatestFrom(
        Observable.combineLatest2(
          emailStream,
          passwordStream,
          (email, password) {
            return CrendentialsDetail(email: email, password: password);
          },
        ), (_, d) {
      return d;
    }).flatMap((d) {
      return Observable.fromFuture(authService.loginUser(d)).doOnListen(() {
        loadingSubject.add(true);
      }).doOnDone(() {
        loadingSubject.add(false);
      });
    }).listen((AuthResponse user) {
      currentUserSubject.add(user);
      _goToHome();
    }, onError: (error) {
      Scaffold.of(_context).showSnackBar(
        new SnackBar(
          content: new Text(error.message),
        ),
      );
    });

    Observable(signUpSubject.stream).withLatestFrom(
        Observable.combineLatest2(
          emailStream,
          passwordStream,
          (email, password) {
            return CrendentialsDetail(email: email, password: password);
          },
        ), (_, d) {
      return d;
    }).flatMap((d) {
      return Observable.fromFuture(authService.register(d)).doOnListen(() {
        loadingSubject.add(true);
      }).doOnDone(() {
        loadingSubject.add(false);
      });
    }).listen((RegisterResponse res) {
      Scaffold.of(_context).showSnackBar(
        new SnackBar(
          content: new Text(res.message),
        ),
      );
    }, onError: (error) {
      Scaffold.of(_context).showSnackBar(
        new SnackBar(
          content: new Text(error.message),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```